# Обнаружение атрибута в сборке без предварительной загрузки в домен .NET

Tags: c#, атрибуты, assembly

Интересует возможно ли узнать наличие определенного атрибута во внешней библиотеке без загрузки библиотеки в домен.
Есть к примеру две сборки:

```
// Основная сборка
namespace FirstAsm
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class InitLoaderAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public Type InitType { get; }
        public InitLoaderAttribute(Type initType)
        {
            InitType = initType;
        }
    }
    ...
}

// Внешняя сборка
[assembly: InitLoader(typeof(MyClass))]
namespace SecondAsm
{
    ...
}
```

Стандартного API для таких целей я не нашел. **AppDomain.Load** не подойдет, т.к. мне прежде всего нужно узнать наличие нужного атрибута. Может есть какие советы

Comment: Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо, как раз то, что нужно мне. Напиши в ответе

Comment: Хотя я поторопился с выводом. В netcore данный метод не поддерживается. Нашел кое какую альтернативу в System.Reflection.Metadata. Проверю будет ли работать

Comment: Как обычно с netcore. В документации  есть, а не деле не работает. И вообще не поймешь что есть, а чего нет. Например на смену Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()  пришел MetadataLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName, но поди попробуй разберись предложено оно только или уже есть. А если и есть то как использовать. Плохо у них с документацией

Comment: В nuget есть System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext, а вот [про него](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15033). Но я не понял как его заставить работать и вообще логику работы.

Comment: [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/)

Comment: @vitidev Документация по MetadataLoadContext недавно появилась: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/inspect-contents-using-metadataloadcontext

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях правильно указали на несколько способов, которые позволяют сделать это:

- Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad (.NET Framework)
- System.Reflection.Metadata (.NET Standard 1.1+)
- System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext (.NET Standard 2.0+)

В .NET Core проще всего воспользоваться третьим способом. Подключаем пакет [System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext/). Вот так мы можем прочитать значение атрибута сборки:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MetadataLoadContextSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputFile = @"C:\Test\Example.dll"; //проверяемая сборка
            string attrFile = @"C:\Test\InitLoader.dll"; //сборка с определением атрибута

            string[] runtimeAssemblies = Directory.GetFiles(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "*.dll");                        
            var paths = new List<string>(runtimeAssemblies);
            paths.Add(inputFile);
            paths.Add(attrFile);
            var resolver = new PathAssemblyResolver(paths);
            var context = new MetadataLoadContext(resolver);

            using (context)
            {                
                Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(inputFile);

                foreach (CustomAttributeData attr in assembly.GetCustomAttributesData())
                {
                    if (String.Equals(attr.AttributeType.Name, "InitLoaderAttribute", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(attr.ConstructorArguments[0].Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```